Variation of Convolution (Hyperfunctions of Exponential Growth)
I'm trying to learn Resurgence Theory reading the book "Borel-Laplace Transform and Asymptotic Theory, Introduction to Resurgent Analysis" by Sternin and Shatalov, and there is a point I'm stuck with:
In the First Chapter, about Laplace transform, it works with Hyperfunctions of Exponential Growth in a fixed direction $\theta$. These are "functions" defined as:

Where the domain is the following (along with other important definitions in the following)

The question is the following: The variation of an hyperfunction of exponential growth is, as its name says, of exponential growth. And in some point, the book introduces the convolution product as an integral in the complex plane as follows:

And then it proves that the convolution of two hyperfunctions of exponential growth is of exponential growth too. For this, the authors compute the variation of this integral, but I don't know how the do this. ¿Any idea? The final result is the following:

¡Thanks in advance!
